# ubuntu, samba, home folder is shown twice in windows 7 with different name

Tags: ubuntu, samba

I've just configured samba for protected sharing home (from linux) to windows machine

```
[homes]
    comment = Home Directories
    browseable = yes
    writable = yes
    read only = no
    create mask = 0700
    directory mask = 0700
    valid users = %S
;   guest ok = no
```

After adding user as smb user too (why is such complicated? why can I just use already existing unix users), I can see in Windows 7 two folders

```
//<server>/homes       <-- this is my home from linux as supposed
//<server>/myusername  <-- this is the same home
```

I really don't know if it's a samba problem or more likely a windows problem. How can I forgot one of those, it's the same thing twice :)

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read "The [homes] section" on [this](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/smb.conf.5.html) page, it says that //server/myusername is cloned on the fly from //server/homes . So, you need to make homes not browseable, aka

```
browseable = no
```

Comment: Oh, incredible! @Mer, thanks very much, worked. Btw, why on earth did they do such a... let's say curious thing... I mean.. why should I ever need a "on fly clone"... doesn't matter. Thanks!